# Docker: Problema ao utilizar o IP dos contêineres

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, docker, ip

Ola, Tudo bem?

A pouco tempo aprendi a utilizar o Docker e decidi por em pratica o uso do mysql e do adminer, com o seguinte docker-compose eu já tinha os contêineres de pé.

```
version: '3.5'

services:

  database:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - '3306:3036'

    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: smartMoft
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root

    volumes:
      - './data:/var/lib/mysql'

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    ports: 
      - '8080:8080'
```

Ao acessar a url do adminer eu tinha acesso a sua bela interface e os bancos de dados do mysql, e utilizando o `docker exec -it ...` eu conseguia acessar o mysql

Entretanto, ao tentar fazer a conexão no nodeJS ele apenas retornava um erro: timeout.

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '172.18.0.2',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'smartMoft',
})
```

Retorno:

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Connection._handleConnectTimeout (C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\estudandoDocker\backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:409:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:435:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:329:20)
    at Socket._onTimeout (node:net:470:8)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:556:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:499:7)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\estudandoDocker\backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\estudandoDocker\backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\estudandoDocker\backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
    at execQuery (C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\estudandoDocker\backend\db\configDB.js:12:16) 
    at C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\estudandoDocker\backend\src\routes.js:10:24
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\estudandoDocker\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\estudandoDocker\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\estudandoDocker\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\estudandoDocker\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\estudandoDocker\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22 {
  errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true
}
```

Vale ressaltar que no campo host o endereço foi retirado de um `docker inspect ...` e que foi testado tanto os ips do mysql, adminer e "localhost", todos sem exito

Vale ressaltar também, que ao utilizar o localhost como host, ele nem timeout dá, mas sim um erro

```
Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\estudandoDocker\backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:112:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\estudandoDocker\backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:94:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\estudandoDocker\backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:341:22)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1294:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:80:21)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\estudandoDocker\backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\estudandoDocker\backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\estudandoDocker\backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
    at execQuery (C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\estudandoDocker\backend\db\configDB.js:12:16) 
    at C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\estudandoDocker\backend\src\routes.js:10:24
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\estudandoDocker\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\estudandoDocker\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\estudandoDocker\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\estudandoDocker\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\estudandoDocker\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22 {
  fatal: true,
  code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'
}
```

Eu ainda tive a ideia de utilizar o beekeeper(Gerenciador de banco de dados), só por via das duvidas, e o mesmo erro era apresentado.

O que mais me intriga, é o fato das credenciais que funcionam no adminer, não funcionarem no beekeeper ou no Node.

A mesma coisa aconteceu quando migrei do mysql para o mongoDB para testar se era algum problema no mysql, utilizei o seguinte código para fazer a conexão:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://root:root@172.19.0.2:27017/smartMoft?authSource=admin', {useNewUrlParser: true}, (err, client) =>{
    if(err) throw err

    console.log(client)
})
```

E o mesmo retornou esse erro apos alguns segundos de espera.

```
aprendendoRedux\api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:19
            throw error;
            ^

MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [172.19.0.2:27017] 
on first connect [MongoNetworkTimeoutError: connection timed out  
    at connectionFailureError (C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\aprendendoRedux\api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:342:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\aprendendoRedux\api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:310:16)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:435:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:329:20)
    at Socket._onTimeout (node:net:470:8)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:556:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:499:7)]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\aprendendoRedux\api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\topologies\server.js:438:11)
    at Pool.emit (node:events:329:20)
    at C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\aprendendoRedux\api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:562:14
    at C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\aprendendoRedux\api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:995:11
    at C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\aprendendoRedux\api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:32:7
    at callback (C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\aprendendoRedux\api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:280:5)  
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sffmo\Desktop\www\Treinos\aprendendoRedux\api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:310:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:435:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:329:20)
    at Socket._onTimeout (node:net:470:8)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:556:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:499:7)
```

Entretanto, funcionava acessar o mongo-express e utilizar de suas credenciais para acessar o banco de dados.

Segue o docker-compose.yml, o mesmo esta na pagina do mongodb no dockerHub.

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: root
```

Sem duvida é um dos problemas mais "problemáticos" que eu já tive na área, e até já tentei pesquisar no google, mas pouquíssimos resultados batiam com minha situação e o resto não resolvia o problema.

Observações:
Estou utilizando root no user e password tanto no mysql quanto no mongodb.
Estou utilizando o Windows 10.
Inicialmente eu utilizava o dockerfile para criar a imagem e comandos como `docker run` para criar o container, mas o mesmo erro era apresentado.
Estou utilizando o Docker desktop

Peço a ajuda de vocês para solucionar esse erro enfadonho que não me abandona

Comment: *"ao tentar fazer a conexão no nodeJS ele apenas retornava um erro: timeout"* onde está a aplicação em node, no mesmo container, outro container, ou no localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Vamos lá, acho que não vou ter a resposta correta... mas tenho algumas sugestões.

> A pouco tempo aprendi a utilizar o Docker e decidi por em pratica o
> uso do mysql e do adminer, com o seguinte docker-compose **eu já tinha
> os contêineres de pé**.

Quando vocẽ diz que já tinha os conteiners de pé, você está dizendo que já possuía ambos rodando, mas queria ter eles rodando usando o docker-compose ?.

Então digamos que esse seja de fato o caso. O que pode ter acontecido é conflito entre portas pois você já tinha um contêiner mongo rodando na porta 8081 ao instanciar outro pelo **docker-compose**, o uso da porta 8081 entrou em conflito, assim a porta permance ocupada.

Descartando esse primeiro caso, pois nas observações você diz que já estava criando os containers com o **Dockerfile** e usando o **docker run** para executa-los.

Vamos lá, primeiro verifique se o contêiner permanece rodando após o **docker run**, usando o comando:

```
docker ps
```

As vezes dependendo dos argumentos passado no comando **run**, o contêiner acabe morrendo/finalizando, eu acredito que continue rodando pois você consegue acessar eles usando o comando **exec**, mas no caso do docker-compose você consegue acessar eles, seguindo os passos anteriores, vamos verificar se os serviços certos estão rodando, caso sim você pode acessar usando o comando exec, veja abaixo:

```
docker-compose ps
docker-compose exec nome_do_servico bash
```

Seguindo para sugestões:

No caso você não está especificando um network_mode para ambos os serviços (mongo e mongo_express), sendo assim o contêiner vai ter ip proprio da sub-rede docker.

Tente subir os contêineres usando a rede do próprio computador, adicione o seguinte trecho abaixo de cada serviço, por exemplo:

```
mongo:
    image: mongo
    network_mode: host
```

vale lembrar que setando os containers para usar a rede "localhost" não é necessário fazer o encaminhamento de portas, pois como já dito ele não vai estar usando a sub-rede docker e sim a rede local do próprio computador.

O que leva a uma outra sugestão, será que por algum motivo o windows está bloqueando as portas do contêineres, nesse sentindo seria legal verificar o firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Docker não foi pensado para você lidar com os IP's dele (embora tenha esse recurso para casos bem peculiares, esse não é teu cenário).

Os IP's dos containers foram projetados para serem dinâmicos, e pior, para serem múltiplos. Ou seja, 2 instâncias de uma aplicação, significa 2 ip's, se são 100 instancias, 100 ip's...

Assim, a forma certa de fazer isso, pela ótica do docker é usar a resolução de nomes interna do docker. As redes docker possuem RESOLUÇÃO DE NOMES (DNS) interno. Basta 2 containers na mesma rede para que essa mágica funcione. Mas não serve usar as redes default, vc tem de criar uma rede nova (não me pergunte o motivo, nunca ficou claro), mas está na doc.

Então você VAI TER de criar uma rede (bridge ou overlay), depois usar essa rede nos 2 containers. Pronto, agora eles se falam pelo nome do container. No docker compose o nome a ser usado é o nome do serviço.